# Flask container is not up and running using docker

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask

So my issue is very simple, but still can't get hold of it and it's not performing like I wanted to.

sample docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
WORKDIR /
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /
RUN chmod a+x start.sh
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["./start.sh"]
```

sample `start.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# sleep 600
nohup python3 /code/app.py &
python3 /code/helloworld_extract.py
```

sample flask app.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return """
  <h1>Python Flask in Docker!</h1>
  <p>A sample web-app for running Flask inside Docker.</p>
  """


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

So, my issue is as soon as I build the image and run it,
`docker run --name flaskapp  -p5000:5000 docker-flask:latest`... I can't reach localhost:5000. 
While if I get inside the container and run explict nohup command with  python3 app.py. I can reach localhost.

So, why can't I reach the localhost host with run command?

The thing is I need to run 2 scripts one is flask and another one is helloworld_extract.py which eventually exit after writing some information to the files.

Comment: Did your main container process (that is, the `helloworld_extract.py`) exit?  Are you sure you don't want two containers here?

Comment: yes...it does exit. No, helloworld_extract is just a scraping script to provide the content to the flask app. after it's initialized.

Answer (score 2):

When your `start.sh` script says

```
#!/bin/sh
do_some_stuff_in_the_background &
some_foreground_process
```

The entire lifecycle of the container is tied to the `some_foreground_process`.  In your case, since you clarify that it's doing some initial data load and exits, once it exits, the `start.sh` script is finished, and so the container exits.

(As a general rule, try to avoid `nohup` and `&` in Docker land, since it leads to confusing issues like this.)

I would suggest making the main container process be *only* the Flask server.

```
CMD ["python3", "/code/app.py"]
```

You don't say what's in the loader script.  Since its lifecycle is completely different from the main application, it makes sense to run it separately; you can replace the `CMD` with `docker run` options.  Say you need to populate some shared data in the filesystem.  You can:

```sh
# Build the image
docker build -t myimage .

# Create a (named) shared filesystem volume
docker volume create extract

# Start the Flask server
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 -v extract:/data myimage

# Run the script to prepopulate the data
docker run -v extract:/data myimage python3 /code/helloworld_extract.py
```

Notice that the same volume name `extract` is used in all the commands.  The path name `/data` is an arbitrary choice, though since both commands run on the same image it makes sense that they'd have the same filesystem layout.

Comment: you are right, thanks for the insight and this helloworld_extract's lifecycle is different from the main application.  But can you suggest, what should be the way, if this helloworld_extract.py is the part of the main application?

Comment: What do you mean by "part of the main application"?  You can pass whatever command line to run it at the end of `docker run` to override the image's CMD.